# BATCH Windows: 30 minutes

Tags: windows, batch-file, minute

I want to do something:

i have a LARGE batch file, but this is what i want to apply to HOLE the batch:

After 30 Minutes, it should display a message.

How is this possible, and can i set this to the hole batch. I kinda have a lot of stuff in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can download sleep.exe from the windows resource kit. OR you can use ping. Otherwise, here's an implementation with vbscript

```
WScript.Sleep WScript.Arguments.Item(0) 'in milliseconds.
```

save as sleep.vbs and use it in your batch

```
cscript /nologo sleep.vbs 3000
```

Comment: It's not going to lock the machine, just the console window that the batch file is running in

Comment: but how do i redirect users when the countdown is over? (using GOTO) and i was not talking about the machine, but the batch file. but that seems to work fine?

Comment: i understand it, but '3000' is not 30 minutes, thats 3 seconds. can you please answer my question above

Comment: 30*60*1000, `%SystemRoot%\system32\calc.exe`. Have fun!

Comment: @yourcomputerhelpz , if you  think you need to change it to minutes, its easy to do. i am sure you how to convert millisecond to minutes. learn to fish by yourself.

Comment: @ghostdog74 , yeah iknow it. I was in a quite sleepy mood so i did not think of calculating it my myself. Well, thanks!